# EncryptedXml DecryptDocument method throws "Bad Data" exception

Tags: c#, wcf, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I wrote a code block for Encrypt/Decrypt Streams.
The code is working in my local machine.
But when I publish my code on web 
The Decryption functions throws "Bad Data" exception
Here is the my Encrypton and Decryption functions

```
private static MemoryStream EncryptStream(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlElement elementToEncrypt, string password)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = password;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
    RijndaelManaged sessionKey = null;
    try
    {

        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rsaKey");
        if (elementToEncrypt == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("elementToEncrypt");

        sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        sessionKey.KeySize = 256;

        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
        byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);

        EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
        edElement.Id = EncryptionElementID;
        edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);

        EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();
        byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, rsaKey, false);
        ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);
        ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

        edElement.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();
        kin.Value = KeyName;

        ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
        edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
        edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));

        EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);

        if (sessionKey != null)
        {
            sessionKey.Clear();
        }
        rsaKey.Clear();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Encoding encodeing = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default;
        return stream;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (sessionKey != null)
        {
            sessionKey.Clear();
        }
        rsaKey.Clear();
        throw (e);
    }
}

private static MemoryStream DecryptStream(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string password)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = password;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
    EncryptedXml exml = null;
    try
    {
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rsaKey");

        exml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);
        exml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, rsaKey);

        exml.DecryptDocument();
        rsaKey.Clear();

        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(outStream);
        outStream.Position = 0;
        return outStream;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        rsaKey.Clear();
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

the exception is thrown on "exml.DecryptDocument();" line.

Do you have any idea about problem and the solution?

> **Edit:**

in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.decryptdocument.aspx) page, there is remark which is as follows

> To use XML Encryption with X.509 certificates, you must have the
>   Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider installed and the X.509
>   certificate must use the Enhanced Provider. If you do not have the
>   Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider installed or the X.509
>   certificate does not use the Enhanced Provider, a
>   CryptographicException with an "Unknown Error" will be thrown when you
>   decrypt an XML document.

Do you have any idea about "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider" and "X.509 certificate"?
And Can my problem be related to this those?

Comment: what is the value of your KeyName in web ?

Comment: I tried the same in my machine also i couldn't simulate. pls share the KeyName value

Comment: I tried out with this key too, but no hope i couldn't simulate. I'm very much doubted on the xml content. Perhaps publish xml content will help me to simulate and help u

Comment: How do you try to simulate the code?
did you encrypta document then try to decrypt witm my code?

Comment: Can you show us your Encrypt method?

Comment: sure, but you should wait for it :)

Comment: I added the encryption code before decryption code.

Comment: Hint: don't use "throw e;". Use "throw;"

Answer (score 4):

The reason the Decryption functions throws "Bad Data" exception when trying to Decrypt on another PC is that the CspParameters is linked to the session on the PC where the Encryption was run.

The cspParams object will need to be  embedded and encrypted in the XML to enable Decryption on another PC. Luckily there is EncryptionProperty we can use for this.

```
private static MemoryStream EncryptStream(XmlDocument xmlDoc, XmlElement elementToEncrypt, string password)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = password;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
    RijndaelManaged sessionKey = null;
    try
    {
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rsaKey");
        if (elementToEncrypt == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("elementToEncrypt");

        sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
        sessionKey.KeySize = 256;

        EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();
        byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);

        EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
        edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
        edElement.Id = EncryptionElementID;
        edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);

        EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();
        byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, rsaKey, false);
        ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);
        ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

        // Save some more information about the key using the EncryptionProperty element.

        // Create a new "EncryptionProperty" XmlElement object. 
        var property = new XmlDocument().CreateElement("EncryptionProperty", EncryptedXml.XmlEncNamespaceUrl);

        // Set the value of the EncryptionProperty" XmlElement object.
        property.InnerText = RijndaelManagedEncryption.EncryptRijndael(Convert.ToBase64String(rsaKey.ExportCspBlob(true)),
                        "Your Salt string here");

        // Create the EncryptionProperty object using the XmlElement object. 
        var encProperty = new EncryptionProperty(property);

        // Add the EncryptionProperty object to the EncryptedKey object.
        ek.AddProperty(encProperty);

        edElement.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();

        KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();
        kin.Value = KeyName;

        ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
        edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
        edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));

        EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);

        if (sessionKey != null)
        {
            sessionKey.Clear();
        }
        rsaKey.Clear();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Encoding encodeing = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default;
        return stream;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (sessionKey != null)
        {
            sessionKey.Clear();
        }
        rsaKey.Clear();
        throw;
    }
}

private static MemoryStream DecryptStream(XmlDocument xmlDoc, string password)
{
    CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
    cspParams.KeyContainerName = password;
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    var keyInfo = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("EncryptionProperty")[0].InnerText;
        rsaKey.ImportCspBlob(
            Convert.FromBase64String(RijndaelManagedEncryption.DecryptRijndael(keyInfo,
                "Your Salt string here")));
    EncryptedXml exml = null;
    try
    {
        if (xmlDoc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("xmlDoc");
        if (rsaKey == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("rsaKey");

        exml = new EncryptedXml(xmlDoc);
        exml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, rsaKey);

        exml.DecryptDocument();
        rsaKey.Clear();

        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(outStream);
        outStream.Position = 0;
        return outStream;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        rsaKey.Clear();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/704372/How-to-use-Rijndael-ManagedEncryption-with-Csharp) for the RijndaelManagedEncryption class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really helped me a lot.

Comment: Always a pleasure and happy it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent cryptography protocols. **You will get it wrong**. Case in point, mishandling the RSA key stored in the [CSPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380245%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and expect them to magically appear on any machine.

To encrypt data in transfer, use SSL/TLS. .Net offers it out-of-the-box with [`SslStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx). For WCF see [How to: Configure an IIS-hosted WCF service with SSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will implement your recommendation but still I need to implement additional encryption in addition to the ssl.
So I have to solve that problem.

Do you have any recommendation for my problem ?